# IBM Worklight reviews for mobile development

Tags: mobile, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I have no prior knowledge on Mobile application development so these might sound a naive question. Basically my requirement is to develop an application that will work on multiple platforms like Android, Blackberry and iOS. Hence, I wanted to know how well is Worklight suited for the job. Basically I wanted to know:

Q1: What are the technical or functionality concerns of Worklight that one should know before going for it.

Q2: Is it better than PhoneGap?

Q3: What are the basic skill sets required for a person to work on Worklight other than Java.

Q4: Are there any Hardware requirements that might be specific to Worklight applications and might cause the developed mobile app to not function on the phone?

I would be grateful to anyone who could help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have no knowledge of mobile application development and you've been tasked with developing one that works across multiple platforms, you may want to polish up the 'ole resume and start looking for a new place to work before they find out.

Answer (score 5):

1. You must buy a license if you intend on going to Production; the free Developer Edition may not be used for that purpose. It's not for individuals or small businesses, but for medium to large businesses. Other than that, it depends on your end goal.
2. Worklight cannot be better than Cordova in the sense that Cordova is bundled within Worklight. So anything you can do in Cordova, you can do in Worklight and add on top of this all the features that Worklight provides you with (and for this, please, just take a look at the [Worklight website](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/worklight/) and [Information Center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp)).
3. You need to know HTML, CSS and JavaScript at a decent to very good level. If you want more, you need to know languages such as Java, Objective-C, C#.
4. No.